# How would you draw tan value from an unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

How would I draw to show the $tan$ value ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to google this? I think there are many resources online ...

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, we need to intersect the line passing throught $(-\sqrt 2/2,-\sqrt 2/2)$ and $(0,0)$ with the vertical line passing throught $(1,0)$.

[image]

(credits: [Trigonometry/Geometric Definitions of Trig Functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Geometric_Definitions_of_Trig_Functions))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to draw all trig functions on the unit circle:[image]